# MySQL insertion batch getting reversed

Tags: mysql, insertion-order

I have a Bash-script doing the following insertion:

```
    for i in $bb; do
            echo "INSERT INTO $D_BASE2.$table2 (id, DokMed_id, amne) SELECT NULL, DokMed_id, amne FROM DokMed_Amne where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE1 2>/dev/null
            echo "UPDATE $D_BASE2.$table2 SET DokMed_id = ${aa} where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE2 2>/dev/null
    done
```

The insertion works fine in to the table 'DokMed_Amne' say 13 new lines. Those lines will have an autoincremented id of 1 till 13.

When I make a new insertion, that previous insertion is moved up to id 14 till 26 and the new instertion gets id 1 till 13. Is this something in MySQL that can be configured? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
First insertion          Second insertion
1   Value 1              1    Value 14
2   Value 2              2    Value 15
3   Value 3              3    Value 16
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
.                        .
13   Value 13            13   Value 26
                         14   Value 1
                         15   Value 2
                         16   Value 3
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         .
                         26   Value 13
```

How could I make Value 1 till 13 stick with id 1 till 13?

Comment: show the create table for the table you are inserting please

Comment: btw show also the correct column names for the table: the update table statement can be the issue if the DokMed_id is the autoincrement id

Comment: *Is this something in MySQL that can be configured?* This can be configured nowhere. In none DBMS.

Comment: Add `created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and use it for sorting the rows in needed order. Use ROW_NUMBER() in CTE if you need to obtain shown rows enumeration (this will be additional output column).

Comment: where is the variable `${aa}` in `SET DokMed_id = ${aa} `defined?

Comment: Looks super obvious. If I understand correctly (the question has missing details) then i runs from 1 to 13 then (i) you're inserting auto increment numbers 14...26 in second iteration (ii) but updating the id values 1...13.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. The answer was rather obvious. They say hindsight is the most accurate science of all:-)

```
 for i in $bb; do
        echo "INSERT INTO $D_BASE2.$table2 (id, DokMed_id, amne) SELECT NULL, DokMed_id, amne FROM DokMed_Amne where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE1 2>/dev/null
        echo "UPDATE $D_BASE2.$table2 SET DokMed_id = ${aa} where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE2 2>/dev/null
 done
```

The script worked as expected edited to this:

```
 for i in $bb; do
        echo "INSERT INTO $D_BASE2.$table2 (DokMed_id, amne) SELECT DokMed_id, amne FROM DokMed_Amne where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE1 2>/dev/null
        echo "UPDATE $D_BASE2.$table2 SET DokMed_id = ${aa} where id = ${i};"| mysql -u eArkiv -p$PASS_WD $D_BASE2 2>/dev/null
 done
```

I guess Salman A had the most accurate explaination, however I'm not really sure why it behaved like this.

Have a nice weekend guys:-)

/Paul